# How can I add hair space (&#8202;) to gsub string?

Tags: ruby, gsub, jekyll-extensions

I have the following line in a plugin to display page views on my Jekyll site:

```
html = pv.to_s.reverse.gsub(/...(?=.)/,'\& ').reverse
```

It adds space between thousands, for example 23 678.

How can I add hair space `&#8202;` instead of regular space in this string?

Comment: You might see if you can copy over Rails' `number_with_delimiter` method. It covers more use cases. For example, what if your number is `23678.45`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML `&#8202;` is a so-called [decimal numeric character reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-references):

> The ampersand must be followed by a "#" (U+0023) character, followed by one or more [ASCII digits](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#ascii-digits), representing a base-ten integer that corresponds to a Unicode code point that is allowed according to the definition below. The digits must then be followed by a ";" (U+003B) character.

Ruby has the [`\u` escape sequence](http://readruby.chengguangnan.com/strings#escapes-summary). However it expects the following characters to represent a hexadecimal (base-sixteen) integer. That's [`200A`](https://codepoints.net/U+200A). You also have to use a double-quoted string literal which means now the `\` character needs to be escaped with another one:

```
"\\&\u200A"
```

Alternatively just use it directly:

```
'\& '
```